# Identifying 2 pipe pieces

Tags: pipe

I'm tasked with producing a barre. This:

[image]

And I'd like to walk into the plumbing supply store with the right words for the parts.
I realize that in screwing pipes together, one can't make a square and so this is needed:

[image]

Can someone tell me what this is?

Last, this guy:

[image]

I can tell that its function was to mount a pipe to a wall, but again, I'm sure there's a word for it. (I am seeing "Iron Floor Flange" on searches along with a couple other names, hoping to confirm that's correct).

Edit: The finished product:

[image]

Total Price: $151.37

My daughter told me the lower cross bar was for younger kids so that went away, and that 4 feet was long enough, as she wasn't ever expecting more than a couple people over.

Comment: Wow, bring money.  That's no small amount of cost in iron pipe. For what it's worth they make 90 degree unions that combine a union and an ell.

Comment: For what it’s worth, as I put the shopping list together, she told me the lower bar wasn’t needed, it’s for the younger kids. So no union either. I will probably pick this all up later in the week. And will update with a picture after I build it along with the total cost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. That is a PIPE UNION.  It is needed where you are unable to screw the threads together normally.  If you look at the structure, you'll be stuck when you try to assemble the top without a union.
2. That is a PIPE FLANGE.  It's not usually used in plumbing per-se but is often used where iron pipes are used for other purposes such as what you are doing.

Comment: Much thanks! Building this for my daughter, and trying to maintain the illusion that I know a bit more than I do.

Comment: That's what we all try to do, @JTP-ApologisetoMonica... Eventually they catch on, but they love you for making the effort! ;)

Comment: Technically, when I order those flanges from the plumbing distributor they are listed as "Floor Flanges".

Answer (score 2):

That's a pipe union,
and the second is a flange.

Comment: you answered at the same time as JWH20, but he was 3 min ahead, so he's getting all the love...

Comment: No, I was first, JWH has more detail